# Losing material set up when joining objects

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm creating a pine tree where the needles have different colours. The branch on the left of the image is how I want it to look, with a yellow tip on the end on the top and pale on the bottom with a darker line along the middle. These are duplicated but separate objects.

As i'm going to have so many, I want to join them as one object. But when I do, I lose the yellow tip and dark line on the bottom. Branch on the right.

I'm assuming this is because when they're joined, they lose their individual local axes? I'm still new to Blender and have tried to find a solution but I just don't know how to work around it.

[image]

Comment: Unwrap your needles and use UV mapping for the color ramp

Comment: Thank you so much!